# Saving concatenated String in one Attribute VS having more Attribute in Core Data? iOS xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

If I want to save in Core Data:

- next destination
- time to next destination
- distance to next destination

would it be more efficient to have three Attributes

```
nextname: String
nextdest: String
nexttime: String
```

or is it better to have just one Attribute and save appended String to it

```
next: String
```

for example if my data were

- next destination = new york
- time to next destination = 30
- distance to next destination = 100

save "newyork_30_100" and do String.componentsSeparatedByString("_") everytime I need to use the data.

VS

have three attributes for each in Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

I would save it as three separate attributes. That way you can filter or sort fetches to core data based on the one particular attribute or a combination of the 3 if you need to.

In terms of efficiency I don't think you'll see much difference saving it one way compared to the other but you'll end up writing more code having to concatenate and then separate the components each time.